# Почему перцептрон не работает корректно?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, numpy

Написал подобный код, который должен являться подобием перцептрона:

```
import numpy as np
import random
inp=np.array([
            [0.9,0.98,0.76],
            [0.1,0.22,0.41]
             ])
out=np.array([[1,0]]) #1 - black, 0 - white
#inp=inp/255
out=out.T
#function
def porog(num):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-num))
#Random weights
weight=2*np.random.random((3,1))-1
print(weight)
#Обучение
for i in range(20000):
    inputed=inp
    output=porog(np.dot(inputed,weight))#Предполагаемое число
    error=out-output #Расчёт ошибки
    k=np.dot(inputed.T,error*(output*(1-output))) # значение вычета ошибки с учетом начальных значений
    weight+=k # Увеличение значения весов для уменьшения ошибки
print('Ошибка',error)
#Тестирование
print('Веса:')
print(weight)
r=float(input('Введите число отвечающее за красное значение цвета: '))
g=float(input('Введите число отвечающее за зеленое значение цвета: '))
b=float(input('Введите число отвечающее за синее значение цвета: '))
num=np.array([r/255,g/255,b/255])
print(porog(np.dot(num,weight)))
```

Данный перцептрон предназначен для определения цвета текста на фоне заданного текста:
На входной слой подаются 3 значения R,G,B представляя собой цвет.
Выходное значение - одно и если оно равно 1, то цвет текста на данном фоне - черный, иначе - белый.
Суть проблемы: при введение значений к примеру белого цвета, в большинстве случаев работает верно, при введении значения черного цвета выдаёт 0.5, что является "неопределённостью". Т.к. в данной области я новичок, то прошу помощи более опытных людей именно тут.

Answer (score 2):

Ваш перцептрон прекрасно выучился на ваших примерах:

```
num = [0.9,0.98,0.76]
print(porog(np.dot(num,weight)))
num = [0.1,0.22,0.41]
print(porog(np.dot(num,weight)))
```

Вывод:

```
[0.987716]
[0.02316886]
```

Почему вы думаете, что он как-то сам обобщит информацию, на которой он учится, до того, чтобы понимать какой цвет светлее, а какой темнее? Да ещё и используя всего два примера. Его задача - найти веса, минимизирующие ошибку на обучающей выборке. Он их нашёл как умел. Для того, чтобы сильнее обобщать данные, полагаю, ему нужно как минимум больше учебных примеров. Но вполне возможно, что один перцептрон вашей модели и не будет способен к таким обобщениям, возможно, вам нужно больше элементов и слоёв нейросети, чтобы научить вашу сеть различать чёрное и белое.
Я вообще пробовал скормить вашему элементу больше разных примеров, ошибка даже на этих примерах только увеличилась в результате. Подозреваю, что вам нужна сигмоида на выходе или ещё какой-то такой пороговый элемент, без которого вы не сможете качественно превращать выход нейросети в дискретные 1 и 0.
В общем, почитайте про нейросети какую-нибудь литературу, в нейросетях все элементы не от балды придуманы, а исходя из теории и практики.